# Go - In a high performance http client for load testing, how can I block/ignore all cookies?

Tags: performance, go, cookies, load-testing

I'm creating tools for my company to load test our system. I currently have tools written in Python but I'm exploring options using Go, hoping for efficiency and performance gains as we need to generate millions of users simultaneously (many thousands per box with many boxes) and every little bit counts. My users primarily make http calls against our system and I need a very lightweight and efficient http client.

For our Python tools, a previous employee had some functions manually dealing with and reusing Sockets and totally ignoring cookies. While I'm totally new to Go, I've compared multiple Go networking implementations so far and I've been happy with CPU and network usage so I don't think I need to go so far as to manually manage sockets yet, but RAM usage has been multiple times higher than in our Python solution. I have a suspicion that's due to these Go implementations automatically maintaining and managing cookies as other higher level Python libraries did the same thing. I'm looking for ways to have my http client disable/block/ignore all cookies to either solve my problem or rule out cookies as my memory bloat culprit.

I've used a simple `net/http` `Get()` call, [fasthttp](http://github.com/valyala/fasthttp) to create a client that reuses varying numbers of connections per hosts (1000+), and creating a `net/http.Client` with and without a custom `Transport`. I've used `pprof` to memory profile each. Without overriding cookies, my http.Client flow seems to have the least memory bloat and fasthttp has the most. I've tried to go through all their docs and searched SO and the web and can't find anything that explicitly ignores or blocks cookies. Closest I found was fasthttp's `DelAllCookies()` for both requests and responses, but calling those had no discernible effect on memory usage. I've looked into `net/http/cookiejar` to set a custom jar and policy for `net/http.Client` but that looks more like a way to store and use cookie data, which I don't want to do, and I don't see a way to set a policy to ignore cookies altogether.

```golang
// fasthttp implementation
var httpClient *fasthttp.Client

func init() {
    httpClient = &fasthttp.Client{
        MaxConnsPerHost: 1000,
    }
}

func fastHTTPClient(method string, uri string) (string, time.Duration) {

    req := fasthttp.AcquireRequest()
    req.Header.SetMethod(method)
    req.SetRequestURI(uri)

    resp := fasthttp.AcquireResponse()

    startTime := time.Now()
    err := httpClient.DoTimeout(req, resp, targetDuration)
    elapsed := time.Since(startTime)

    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)

        body := string(resp.Body())
        req.Header.DelAllCookies()
        resp.Header.DelAllCookies()
        fasthttp.ReleaseRequest(req)
        fasthttp.ReleaseResponse(resp)
        return body, elapsed
    }

    body := string(resp.Body())
    req.Header.DelAllCookies()
    resp.Header.DelAllCookies()
    fasthttp.ReleaseRequest(req)
    fasthttp.ReleaseResponse(resp)
    return body, elapsed
}

// net/http implementation
var tr = &http.Transport{}
var client = &http.Client{Transport: tr}

func netGet(method string, uri string) (string, time.Duration) {

    startTime := time.Now()
    resp, err := client.Get(uri)
    elapsed := time.Since(startTime)

    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)

        body, err2 := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        resp.Body.Close()

        if err2 != nil {
            log.Panic(err)
        }

        return string(body), elapsed
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    resp.Body.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }

    return string(body), elapsed
}
```

Again, these work functionally but when I run thousands of these concurrently using [boomer](https://github.com/myzhan/boomer) I end up using multiple GB of RAM vs 1-1.5 GB with our Python Sockets implementation. How can I block/ignore cookies or otherwise be sure cookies aren't what's eating up all my memory?

Comment: You're deleting cookies from the request when you never set any in the first place, so that's completely unnecessary. Deleting the cookies off the response is also unnecessary since you're not reusing it. "Ignoring cookies" would just mean disregarding that response header; since that's a pretty unusual use case, you'd likely have to write your own client to do so.

Comment: For net/http there simply is no _need_ to do much with cookies (and nothing you can do anyway). If memory pressure really comes from cookie values: Just empty each cookie's value (maybe name too) directly after receiving. Thats all you can do as there is _no_ _way_ to make net/http _not_ read the cookies sent over the wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fasthttp will always load the full response into memory. So if you're having large response bodies and want to limit memory usage it's probably not the best solution for you.

Fasthttp also trades memory usage for CPU usage by keeping buffers in memory and reusing it instead of spending CPU cycles having these buffers collected by the garbage collector.

Using multiple GBs of memory seems a lot. Are you looking at the RSS or maybe the virtual memory in this case?

Comment: Good info on fasthttp. Thanks. I'm not looking at virtual memory, I'm looking at RSS. I can watch that tick up until the process is killed because `out of memory`. It's definitely possible that I'm doing something that's more expensive in Go than Python. Could be the work I'm doing with the response body. I'll look into that.

Comment: After additional attempts to track down and reduce the memory usage, it does appear like it's less cookies and more handling the response the bodies. I'll have to keep going down that route. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: How big are your response bodies?

Comment: You might like the new Go 1.13 that will be released soon: https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.13#runtime

`The runtime is now more aggressive at returning memory to the operating system to make it available to co-tenant applications. Previously, the runtime could retain memory for five or more minutes following a spike in the heap size. It will now begin returning it promptly after the heap shrinks. However, on many OSes, including Linux, the OS itself reclaims memory lazily, so process RSS will not decrease until the system is under memory pressure. `

Answer (score 1):

A cookie is just a header contained in the Response. You can't prevent a header from being returned by the server. You can only accept it and read it in memory. Although the browser can disable local cookies, it still does not prevent the server from returning a header with a set-cookie header.

As for Fasthttp, I saw a bit of source code and find it used a lot of sync. Pool to improve performance, but I did not find that its purpose is to save memory. Its purpose is only fast.

If you value memory very much, I recommend simply wrapping it on http/net or find another package instead of using fasthttp, which is not suitable for stress testing.